# How do I merge two or more results from elasticsearch rails gem?

Tags: elasticsearch, merge, ruby-on-rails-5, elasticsearch-rails

I'm trying to merge two elasticsearch results into one variable, here my code tries...

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
    def index

    end

    def advanced
        @results = {}

        if !params[:fast_search].empty?
                @results[:features] = TestCases.search(params[:fast_search]).results
                @results[:steps] = Steps.search(params[:fast_search]).results
                @results[:examples] = Examples.search(params[:fast_search]).results
        else
            unless params[:feature].blank?
                features = TestCases.search(query: { match: { function: params[:feature] } }).results
                features_tag = Steps.search(query: { match: { tags: params[:tags] } }).results
                @results[:features] = features + features_tag
            end

            unless params[:steps].blank? || params[:scenario].blank?
                @results[:steps] = Steps.search(query: { match: { scenario: params[:scenario] } }).results
                params[:steps].each do |step|
                    @results[:steps] += Steps.search(query: { match: { steps: step } }).results
                end
                @results[:steps] += Steps.search(query: { match: { tags: params[:tags] } }).results
            end

            unless params[:examples].blank?
                params[:examples].each do |example|
                    @results[:examples] += Examples.search(query: { match: { examples: example } }).results
                end
                @results[:examples] += Examples.search(query: { match: { tags: params[:tags] } }).results
            end

            unless params[:bug].blank?
                @results[:miscs] = StepsMiscs.search(query: { match: { bug: true } }).results
            end
        end

        render "search/index"
    end
end
```

I also try `features.merge(features_tag)` but no success either.

It's simple, I just need to merge one and more results from the elasticsearch, but I simply don't know how.

Here's my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0', '>= 5.0.0.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# jQuery-Turbolinks
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'

# Mysql
gem 'mysql2'

# Safe Attributes
gem 'safe_attributes'

# Elastic Search
gem 'elasticsearch-model'
gem 'elasticsearch-rails'
gem 'elasticsearch-persistence'
gem 'pry'

#rake
gem 'rake'

#sidekiq
gem 'sidekiq'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console'
end

group :production do
  #passenger
  gem "passenger", require: "phusion_passenger/rack_handler"
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

And here's obviously the error that I'm getting:

```
undefined method `+' for #<Elasticsearch::Model::Response::Results:0x0000000d2719f8>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here after a lot of search, I've found this:

```
    unless params[:steps].blank? || params[:scenario].blank? || params[:tags].blank?
            query = Jbuilder.encode do |json|
              json.query do
                json.match do
                  json.scenario do
                    json.query params[:scenario]
                  end
                end
                params[:steps].each do |step|
                    json.match do
                      json.tags do
                        json.query step
                      end
                    end
                end
                json.match do
                  json.tags do
                    json.query params[:tags]
                  end
                end
              end
            end
            @results[:steps] = Steps.search(query).results
        end
```

This help me to search more than one match on all my models.
I know that catch only the basics, but at the moment is part for what I need and I hope this could help all the others around here with the same issue!

Thanks you all!